# Docksend in Transmit 4 by Panic no longer works after upgrading to OS 10.7.3

Tags: macos, ftp

I've just upgraded to OS 10.7.3 and Docksend in Transmit 4 by Panic no longer works. I drop files on the dock icon and nothing happens in Transmit.

Comment: I'm reopening this since even though few people might still run 10.7.3 - there is useful information even if this sits in a dark corner of the site. Unless the information is actively wrong, let's leave this on the site since it's not clear this really is tied to 10.7.3...

Answer (score 2):

I used the **Using DockSend** help menu and it worked like a charm for me. I'm on 10.7.3 as well:

You might just need to toggle it off, wait (perhaps reboot) and toggle it back on. Here are detailed instructions from the help menu:

[image]

So, following that, you'll end up here:

[image]

Make sure that **Use DockSend** checkbox is checked! If it is and it still won't work, I would reinstall Transmit. If it still won't work after that, definitely contact Panic support.